# Why isn't typescript inferring return type correctly based on params passed?

Tags: typescript

I have this function with a switch case that returns two different results based on the case.

```js
export function getTimeAgo(
  date: Date | string,
  mode: "days" | "minutes" = "days"
) {
  if (typeof date === "string") {
    date = new Date(date);
  }
  switch (mode) {
    case "days":
      return getTimeAgoByDays(date);
    case "minutes":
      return getTimeAgoByMinutes(date);
    default:
      return { timeAgo: "", numFormat: null };
  }
}
```

The `getTimeAgoByDays` function:

```js
function getTimeAgoByDays(date: Date) {
  let timeAgo = "";
  const curDate = new Date();
  const days = Math.round(
    (date.valueOf() - curDate.valueOf()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
  );

  if (days === 0) {
    timeAgo = "Ends today";
  } else if (days < 0) {
    const nonNegativeDays = days * -1;
    timeAgo = `${nonNegativeDays} days behind`;
  } else {
    timeAgo = `${days} days left`;
  }
  if (days === 1) {
    timeAgo = timeAgo.replace("days", "day");
  }

  return { timeAgo, numFormat: days };
}
```

Then calling it to get the results:

```js
const { timeAgo, numFormat: days } = getTimeAgo(date,"days");
```

In the `days` variable I get an error stating that it could be `null`. But based on the `mode`, `days`, shouldn't the result always be non-`null`?

Comment: what is `getTimeAgoByMinutes()` ?

Comment: It's a function similar to by days, but for the purpose of the question it can be removed. In my code it was the same as the by days so it didn't make a difference to include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypyScript does not do any control flow analysis to determine the return type of a function based on the input values and the code inside the function. When you hover over the definiton of `getTimeAgo`, you will see that the return type is just a union of all the different things the function returned.

```
{
    timeAgo: string;
    numFormat: number;
} | {
    timeAgo: string;
    numFormat: null;
}
```

So no matter what you pass to the function, the return type will always be this union where `numFormat` could be `null`.

You can change this behaviour with function overloading. Here you explicitly tell TypeScript what the return type will be based on the arguments.

```
export function getTimeAgo<
  T extends "days" | "minutes"
>(date: Date | string, mode: T): { 
  timeAgo: string, numFormat: T extends "days" | "minutes" ? number : null 
}

export function getTimeAgo(
  date: Date | string,
  mode: "days" | "minutes" = "days"
) {
  /* ... */
}
```

In the return type we can create conditions based on `T` and form a fitting return type accordingly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwObAwAqmAtsAIJ4QA8AUHHEXKDMCgCYDOcARBwEMAnl15wAPn1KYUSNqLoA%20ABSC2ALjgARAWwlwuMKDLwAaOKQgdgmogEpNAbzhZyVCJsPGUZuLNIAYtCkurYsIGycPPzCovq80rLyYgD8fkikAEbAUHCasgA2BXAAvnR0oJCwiKgY2LgExGSU1MoMcGo22rrA%20l4mpu2W1poxImKSCTJywHEAvHyC43R2cI7tmAhwyjBCYMAQW51wc6d8-T68q%20uMjMcLKMAA7t1sqj12ANztZYxcT5gYGgABbbYbAa7tRhoARcXpjUTqKG3KCEJBQBqEEhuagAISEOhE7zYX2RMLhUmmySRtxRaIxa1cLQ8fAEKCEMGBJl45n8QSgIRgmgATABmErfWnWBACJAFIXIxiomDo3DOJnuUY89KBYKhdJFUqS0p0Mp0ZDoLA4fBY5rufGErjEro6ElrdoFQguO3UE58XjGtA4QxwNDo129B7PV7AZSk6HB%20BLHgLACyumBADooBBUBw2rTnZmAG4CApIYAAeQQcbgAFpQ%20GeiWyxXq3HVgB6bYARgADAO4AAqOAANj7w7HE5HwoALHZ2qSNlt3iITmc%205DaRrfQteABRKIuKzCAM-FgFCmbbbJuA0OCb920oMoEMoHAAOWAeF0mGLwEdP1bxHOse2NRgdwgP0AAMABJHHfFAvx-LB-0dEoOliOBsi5ThoONDDgEvXobluSCYPg5MMNvT0EBgfCfmXG8sNOBYey3MifSghZIOzYAwAKAQ0FjBFtTGK4CPKJV6TVb0cQgXkMn5QVNFvCVTXKF8Q1RFMbSaeTlEeF4IzjcxRNJLT4B0ns-UabFmUM6MTLsMzEhmUQviAA)

But in the code you provided this does not seem to be necessary. You could also just remove the `default` clause of the switch statement, since it is not reachable.